# How many times have the number occured in a row(Java)

Tags: java

I'm supposed to create a mainmethod that calculates how many times a number have occured in a row. The user is supposed to input the numbers.
I guess I have to loop through an array though I'm not sure how..

Userinput to array, loop through and check if the number is the previous one.

Example:
1 3 4 5 6 6 6 9 - Output: The number 6 occured 3 times in a row

This is the code I have right now(sry missed to paste it):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    int counter = 0;
    int[] x = new int[inp.nextInt()];
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
        if(i == x[i])
        {
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(counter);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: We're not going to write the code for you. If you attempt it, and have problems, if you attempt it and want help making it more efficient once it's working, then you can post the code on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What should the output be for your example input?

Comment: @Michelle "The number 6 occured three times in a row"

Answer (score 1):

Use a `HashMap<Integer, Long>` to track the number of occurences for each number:

```
Map<Integer, Long> numberOccurences = new HashMap<>();
for(int n : numbers) {
    Long occurences = numberOccurences.get(n);
    if(occurrences == null) {    // first time the number n is seen
        numberOccurences.put(n, 1L);
    } else {
        numberOccurences.put(n, occurences + 1);
    }
}
```